# Read black and white image with OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I tried to simply read a binary mask image that I have created. When I read it using

```
bw_mask = cv2.imread('image.png')
```

the image is read as a numpy array of zeros that looks like:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    ...,
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    ...,
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    ...,
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]],

   ...,

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    ...,
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    ...,
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    ...,
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Could you please explain to me why, I really want to learn the reason in depth but in a clear layman words. the colored image opens just as a typical image(not array).

Why is it possible to read it, if these operations are applied?

```
bw_mask = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
bw_mask = bw_mask.view(np.int32)
img_cv_16bit = bw_mask.astype(np.uint16)
img_cv_8bit = np.clip(img_cv_16bit // 16, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
result = cv2.resize(img_cv_8bit, (800, 600), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

I still do not understand why this works, I would appreciate your explanation and answering.

Comment: What are the actual properties of the input PNG you're using -- number of channels, bits per channel, etc.?

Comment: "got the result I want, using this code" -- honestly most of that doesn't really make much sense. You said it's a binary mask, so why the shinanigans with 32bit integer view, and then treating it as iif it was a 12bit grayscale.... What's the actual problem? Just not reading the [documentation of `imread`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.9.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) and not being aware that default value for the second argument is `IMREAD_COLOR`?

Comment: You can share the image without modification if you use Dropbox, Google Drive or Github etc.

Comment: Your image has an entirely pointless alpha channel with no information in it. It also has three identical RGB channels, which make it look grey - so it actually has 4 channels (RGBA) when it really only needs a single channel. Furthermore, it is not black and white but has over 250 unique shades of grey. It looks like all zeroes in your printout because you are only seeing the top few and last few rows of the image which are all black, i.e. zero.

Comment: If you are expecting the image to be pure black and white (no shades of grey) you can use the code suggested by @Reinderien and follow it up with `cv.threshold()` to get all pixels to be either 0 or 255.

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you, yes It is my fault I was not aware of cv2.IMREAD_GREYSCALE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine, though you should be explicit about only caring about grayscale:

```py
import cv2

bw_mask = cv2.imread(
    filename='wrwoW.png',
    flags=cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE,
)
print(bw_mask.min())
print(bw_mask.max())
print(bw_mask.sum())
```

```
0
255
704116830
```

This is especially true since (for some reason) the image you posted isn't actually saved in grayscale:

[image: image properties]

```
wrwoW.png: PNG image data, 2340 x 1900, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

Comment: It's quite possible that Imgur modified the original image after upload.